# How to pull in additional private repositories in Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

Trying to use AWS Amplify to deploy a multi-repo [dendron](https://wiki.dendron.so) wiki which has a mix of public and private github repositories.

Amplify can be associated with a single repo but there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to pull in additional private repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom [deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys) for the private repo in github

   - generate the key

   ```sh
   ssh-keygen -f deploy_key -N ""
   ```
2. Encode the deploy key as a base64 encoded env variable for amplitude

   ```sh
   cat deploy_key | base64 | tr -d \\n
   ```

   - add this as a hosting [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#amplify-console-environment-variables) (eg. DEPLOY_KEY)
3. Modify the `amplify.yml` file to make use of the deploy key

   - there's 2 key steps

     - adding deploy key to `ssh-agent`

       - WARNING: this implementation will print the `$DEPLOY_KEY` to `stdout`
     - disabling `StrictHostKeyChecking`

       - NOTE: amplify does not have a `$HOME/.ssh` folder by default so you'll need to create one as part of the deployment process
   - relevant excerpt below

   ```yaml
   - ...
   - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   - ssh-add <(echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | base64 -d)

   - echo "disable strict host key check"
   - mkdir ~/.ssh
   - touch ~/.ssh/config

   - 'echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
   - ...
   ```

   - full build file [here](https://github.com/kevinslin/kevin-public-garden/blob/main/amplify.yml)

Now you should be able to use git to clone the private repo.

For a more detailed writeup as well as alternatives and gotchas, see [here](https://kevinslin.com/notes/6a6zlabtuxiralfjc44ybzm)

Comment: Even after following all these steps, still getting Host key verification failed.

Answer (score 0):

For **GitLab** repositories:

1. Create a deploy token in GitLab
2. Set env variables (eg. DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME, DEPLOY_TONE_PASSWORD) in amplify panel
3. Add this line to the amplify config

   ```
   - git config --global url."https://$DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME:$DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD@gitlab.com/.../repo.git".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/.../repo.git"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update multiple submodules with ssh keys you should either use one ssh key for all submodules (ssh key of machine user for example) either follow next flow:

1. add ssh-key for repo1
2. update repo1
3. clean ssh-keys
   ...

Took me a while to figure out